# How to apply ng-repeat for such structure

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to retrieve a collection of items and then display in the UI properties listed under those. The problem is that the JSON I am receiving from one of the services is causing problems:

Instead of a structure which I would normally expect, i.e.

```
"items": [
    {
        "field1": "value1",
        "field2": "value2",
        "id":"ABCDEF1234"
    },
    {
        "field1": "value1",
        "field2": "value2",
        "id":"XYZ12345"
    }
]
```

I am receiving:

```
"items": [
    {
      "ABCDEF1234": {
        "field1": "value1",
        "field2": "value2",
        "id":"ABCDEF1234"

      }
    },
    {
      "XYZ12345": {
        "field1": "value1",
        "field2": "value2",
        "id":"XYZ12345"
      }
    }
]
```

Normally I would assign 'items' to $scope.items and then would use ng-repeat like this:

```
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
      <ul>
        <li>{{item.id}}</li>
        <li>Field1 - {{item.field1}}</li>
        <li></li>Field2 - {{item.field2}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

But in this case each item is represented by dynamic id which apart from being displayed as one of the fields is also used as a key of the object. How should I iterate through such collection using ng-repeat to display something like this:

ABCDEF1234
field1 - value1
field2 - value2

XYZ12345
field1 - value1
field2 - value2

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: This is standard ng-repeat procedure. Can you share what you have tried so far? How is the JSON causing problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div ng-repeat="(itemKey, itemValue) in item">
        <h2>{{ itemKey }}</h2>
        <ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in itemValue" ng-if="key !== 'id'">
            <li>{{ key }} - {{ value }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

you could just map it into a more usable format when you recieve it. e.g.

```
items = items.map(item => item.values[0]);
```

This would map it into

```
[
  {
    "field1": "value1",
    "field2": "value2",
    "id": "ABCDEF1234"
  },
  {
    "field1": "value1",
    "field2": "value2",
    "id": "XYZ12345"
  }
]
```

Comment: arrow function?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.items = [{
    "ABCDEF1234": {
      "field1": "value1",
      "field2": "value2",
      "id": "ABCDEF1234"

    }
  }, {
    "XYZ12345": {
      "field1": "value1",
      "field2": "value2",
      "id": "XYZ12345"
    }
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in item">
      {{key}}
      <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in value" ng-if="key!== 'id'">
        {{key}}-{{value}}
      </div>
      <br/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for those details.

Answer (score 0):

ng-repeat causes performance issues if you have a large list.It will create a number of child scopes and watchers.It is better to limit the use of ng-repeat.I suggest you modify the data in required format and then use single ng-repeat.